# Add a persistent view to RNN inside a TabBar controller

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I want to add a persistent view inside of a tabbar like the Apple Music app showing below.

[image: Apple Music]

Currently, I can add this component to the bottom of each screen but it would be great if there was a way to attach it to the tabbar so that there is only one instance of it in the app and it hasn't have to re-rendered with new screen of tab pressed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for RNN v2, I solved this using @guy.gc suggestion of adding a persistent overlay that loads on the first screen's componentDidMount.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by defining your own `TabBarComponent`.

You can add a property name `tabBarComponent` in your `TabNavigator` like this -

```
export const TabBar =  TabNavigator({
    Music: Music,
    Artists: Artists,
    Composers: Composers,
    Recents: Recents,
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        return <YourIconComponent color={tintColor} />
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'red',
      inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
    },
    tabBarComponent: TabBarComponent,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  }
);
```

And then you can define your own `TabBarComponent` like this -

```
import React from 'react'
import { TabBarBottom } from 'react-navigation'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

class TabBarComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.yourTabBarContainerStyle}>
        <YourFixedComponent />
        <TabBarBottom {...this.props} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default TabBarComponent;
```

...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey @Arpit do you know if this is possible with RNN v2?

Comment: How about implementing it using HOC. That should work with any library.

Comment: @dmathewwws This is possible in v2 using Overlay

Comment: Are you sure about that @guy.gc? 

https://gist.github.com/dmathewwws/0d5b63df90b37a2a194d7df1c26f9345


This is how I set up the overlay but you cannot define the overlay component, it just sets the tabbar as the overlay

Comment: Hey, yes instead of adding the overlay to the options of the tabbar component I think it could work by adding an overlay to the first screen of the app.